# Linux, How to merge (show ) more folders in one? (symlink, or other solution)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symlink, directory, kodi

I am trying to create a script, which will go through the SRC folders, collect all the folders which matches the TEXT label.
Then will create the LIBRARY folder.
Hereby i need some advice, how to mount/symlink/merge all the subfolders (folders and files) which are located under SRC/"criteria" folders and link to one place - LIBRARY.

> example: A:/mnt/hdd_1.5T/Movies.All/*"*all files and folders*"
>
> B:/mnt/hdd_1.5T/Movies.Else/*"*all files and folders*"
>   or more....
>
> link to /mnt/Library.Movies/ 
>   -- here i want to see all folders and files from
>   A and B or more
>
> The current script not exactly works.
>   Shows:
>   /mnt/Library.Movies/~Movies.All
>   /mnt/Library.Movies/~Movies.Else

```
#! /bin/bash

SRC="/mnt/hdd_1.5T
/mnt/hdd_4T"

MOVIES_TEXT="Movies.*"
MOVIES_LIB="/mnt/Library.Movies"

rm -rf $MOVIES_LIB

#find $SRC -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$MOVIES_TEXT"
FULL_DIRS=$(find $SRC -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$MOVIES_TEXT")
mkdir -p $MOVIES_LIB
cd $MOVIES_LIB
ln -s $FULL_DIRS $MOVIES_LIB
```

Comment: Use [mergefs](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs)

Comment: sounds a bit overcomplicated. However i looked at it, but not the solution i need right now.

Comment: I will answer my comment, got a good advice: with symlinks. find $MOVIE_DIRS -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ln -sf -t $MOVIES_LIB {} +
find $MOVIE_DIRS -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.*" -exec ln -sf -t $MOVIES_LIB {} +